# Fill up web HTML text field page with browser console

Tags: javascript, html, web, browser, console

I am a motorsport engineer, so I don't know many things about HTML, web and all those things (#MATLABforlife), but I would like to do something, and don't know how to do, and its look pretty easy for real programmer:

I've got a web page, with a text field, that I identified with dev tools, lets say:

```html
<div placeholder="Search car..." contenteditable="true" role="textbox" spellcheck="true" class="gencar-editor"></div>
```

When I type something like "McLaren MP4" it looks like:

```html
<div placeholder="Search car..." contenteditable="true" role="textbox" spellcheck="true" class="gencar-editor">McLaren MP4</div>
```

How do I put text into this field, like I did, but using console instead of clicking in it and typing? A sort of:

> gencar-editor="McLaren MP4" (but its obviously doesn't work)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using JavaScript :

`var edit = document.getElementsByClassName('gencar-editor');`

`edit.innertText = 'McLaren MP4';`

Documentation is here :https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp

Also, you can use jQuery, like :

`$('.gencar-editor').text('McLaren MP4');`

I hope this helps you.

Comment: It works, but dont fill nothing into the field, just displaying 'McLarenMP4' on Console

Comment: Use ```textContent = 'McLarenMP4'``` instead of ```innerText```